# HTTP Basic Authorization header in request using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS with an external API. The API uses HTTP Basic for authentication.

I have looked around at how to do this but nothing seems to work. The OPTIONS request is always sent without the Authorization header.

Here is some example code:

```
 var app = angular.module("BE", []);

        app.controller("NextCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic encoded_credentials';
            $http.get('http://api-url.com').
                success(function(data, status, headers) {
                  $scope.event = data.Event;
                  $scope.race = data.Race;
                  $scope.entrants = data.Entrants
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  // log error
            });

        });
```

How can I make my requests with the Authorization header set for every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control that because OPTIONS is sent by a browser. A browser removes any authorization data in OPTION requests (see [CORS W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0)).

In most cases `Authorization` header for OPTIONS-requests isn't needed because the response includes only CORS headers and doesn't perform any action.